# How do I enter Segoe MDL2 Assets character from a keyboard on Windows 10?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I need to do some design work for UWP app in Illustrator and I need to use a few symbols from Segoe MDL2 Assets. I'm able to copy and paste them to Illustrator from here http://modernicons.io/segoe-mdl2/cheatsheet/

The problem is that aforementioned page has only a fraction of characters from the entire font: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font

Perhaps, I'm missing something, but everything I found on the Internet doesn't work on Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the Character Map (charmap.exe) application to copy and paste characters from Segoe MDL2 Assets to Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to insert symbols into Microsoft Office, go to Insert > Symbols > More Symbols...

On the top left, click the "Font:" dropdown menu and select "Segoe MLD2 Assets". Double-click the symbol you want.

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of use to you, but in some applications, such as Word, you can type in the Unicode number for the character you want and immediately follow with an Alt-X to enter the character - Word immediately converts it after the Alt-X is pressed.

For example, if I wanted Segoe MDL2 Assets character U+F71E, which seems to be a picture of a desktop computer, I enter f71e followed by an Alt-X and Word display the character.

Comment: Hi Dave, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to avoid answers that may be ambiguous in their relevance to OP.